# Populate a TableView with data from a Firestore

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, uitableview, google-cloud-firestore

I am having trouble with populating my table view. When I run this code it does not populate the table view at all. I am sure it is retrieving the data from firebase.

```
    var restaurants: [Restaurants] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        videos = fetchData()
        configureTableView()
    }
```

here is my extension function:

```
extension RestaurantViewController {
    func fetchData() -> [Restaurants]{

        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        db.collection("Restaurants").getDocuments { (snapshot, err) in

            if let err = err {
                print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
                return
            } else {
                for document in snapshot!.documents {

                    let name = document.get("Name") as! String

                    print("Name: ",name)
                    let restaurant1 = Restaurants(title: name)

                    self.restaurants.append(restaurant1)

                }

            }
        }

        return restaurants

    }
```

I probably missing something simple, please assist

Thanks!

Comment: You’re sure you retrieve data from Firebase, but does your fetchData return a populated array? If so I would go on debugging the tableView delegate methods. Perhaps then you can share them with us. I assume configureTableView deals with that?

Comment: you are missing a MVVM. See for example: https://medium.com/@niamhpower/getting-started-with-firebase-on-ios-part-2-f1de3621007a

Comment: @DanAbnormal Ive just checked there, it does not return a populated array. any ideas on how I can make sure its populated before returning?

Comment: @mick1996 I posted a possible solution using a completion handler.

Comment: @mick1996 you could also try to return the array at the same place as my completion(true), but I'm not using returns that much to be honest. Your problem is, however, that you return your array before the async database call has been executed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this instead

```
func fetchData(completion: @escaping (Bool) -> ()){

    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    db.collection("Restaurants").getDocuments { (snapshot, err) in

        if let err = err {
            print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
            completion(false)
        } else {
            for document in snapshot!.documents {

                let name = document.get("Name") as! String

                print("Name: ",name)
                let restaurant1 = Restaurants(title: name)

                self.restaurants.append(restaurant1)

            }

            completion(true)
        }
    }
}
```

In your viewDidLoad:

```
fetchData { (done) in

    if done {
        configureTableView()
    } else {
        // Handle this somehow
    }
}
```